# Question about some equivalents to "inasmuch as" and "holding fast" in this passage

Tags: word-choice

Could you simplify the highlighted parts in simple English, please? A million thanks in advance.

> The essence of these words is this: they that tread the path of faith, they that thirst for the wine of certitude, must cleanse themselves of all that is earthly—their ears from idle talk, their minds from vain imaginings, their hearts from worldly affections, their eyes from that which perisheth. They should put their trust in God, and,  **holding fast unto Him** , follow in His way. Then will they be made worthy of the effulgent glories of the sun of divine knowledge and understanding, and become the recipients of a grace that is infinite and unseen, **inasmuch as** man can never hope to attain unto the knowledge of the All-Glorious, can never quaff from the stream of divine knowledge  and wisdom, can never enter the abode of immortality, nor partake of the cup of divine nearness and favour, unless and until he ceases to regard the words and deeds of mortal men as a standard for the true understanding and recognition of God and His Prophets.
>
> The Kitáb-i-Íqán
> Author: Bahá’u’lláh

Answer (score 2):

*Holding* is simple enough, but *fast* is an archaic usage. In connection with *holding*, it would be the equivalent to "***tightly***" producing this modern paraphrase of the entire sentence:  "They should put their trust in God, ***hold tightly onto him***,  and follow in His way."

In that paragraph, *Inasmuch as* seems to be best replaced by "***since***", but if you are really looking for simplicity, the entire sentence should be paraphrased.

Answer (score 0):

This is purely a personal choice, but I would go with:

1) "holding fast unto Him" - "staying true to Him"

2) "inasmuch as" - "considering that" *or* "recognising that*